# (list) in lazy-seq causes infinite recursion but (cons) does not

Tags: clojure, lazy-sequences

In attempting to understand lazy-seq, I came up with this example:

```
(defn zeroes []
  (list 0 (lazy-seq (zeroes))))

(take 5 (zeroes)) ; too much recursion error
```

This however triggers a too much recursion error. Replacing (list) with (cons) fixes the problem, but I don't understand why:

```
(defn zeroes []
  (cons 0 (lazy-seq (zeroes))))

(take 5 (zeroes))  ; returns (0 0 0 0 0)
```

My understanding of lazy-seq is that it immediately returns a lazy-seq instance but that its body is not evaluated until a call to first or rest on that instance. So I would think (zeroes) would just return a simple Cons of 0 and a LazySeq with a yet unevaluated body.

As an additional curiosity, I'm puzzled why this hangs the repl (because the repl attempts to print an infinite sequence) but doesn't trigger a 'too much recursion' error.

```
(defn zeroes []
  (cons 0 (lazy-seq (zeroes))))

(zeroes)  ; hangs the repl
```

(In case it's relevant, I'm trying these examples in the ClojureScript repl at http://himera.herokuapp.com/index.html.)

Answer (score 1):

You asked two questions...

> 1) Why does using `list` instead of `cons` in the following code result in infinite recursion?

```
(defn zeroes []
  (cons 0 (lazy-seq (zeroes))))

(take 5 (zeroes)) ; too much recursion error
```

The version using `cons` produces an infinite sequence of zeros, like this:

```
(0 0 0 0 ...)
```

If you use `list` instead, you produce a totally different result. You get an infinite nesting of lists of two elements each (with *head=0* and *tail=another list*):

```
'(0 (0 (0 (0 (...))))
```

Since the top-level list only has two elements, you end up with the *whole thing* when you call `(take 5)`. You get the "too much recursion" error when the REPL tries to print out these infinitely-nested lists.

Note that you could safely substitute the [`list*`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/list*) for `cons`. The `list*` function takes a variable number of arguments (as does `list`), but unlike `list` it assumes the last argument is a *seq*. This means `(list* a b c d)` is essentially just shorthand for `(cons a (cons b (cons c d)))`. Since `(list* a b)` is basically the same as `(cons a b)`, it follows that you can make the substitution in your code. In this case it probably wouldn't make much sense, but it's nice if you're `cons`-ing several items at the same time.

---

> 2) Why does the following diverge (hang) rather than throw a "too much recursion" error like we saw above?

```
(defn zeroes []
  (cons 0 (lazy-seq (zeroes))))

(zeroes)  ; hangs the repl
```

The `zeros` function produces a "flat" sequence of zeros (unlike the nested lists above). The REPL probably uses a tail-recursive function to evaluate each successive lazy element of the sequence. The tail-call optimization allows recursive functions to recur forever without blowing the call stack—so that's what happens. Recursive tail-calls in Clojure are denoted by the [`recur` special form](http://clojure.org/special_forms#recur).

Comment: Thanks. I actually did figure out I was misunderstanding the cons/list distinction and what lazy-seq's body should return. I'm curious though why list* is so named when it returns a Cons rather than a PersistentList. Is it possible for the node chain of a PersistentList to end in a sequence? Or can only Cons do that?

Comment: The name `list*` is just tradition. I think all the other Lisp/Scheme variants have a similar function. [Common Lisp has it](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_list_.htm#listST), and [so does Racket](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html?q=list*#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._list%2A%29%29).